# signal mapping issue with QlineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I want to pass the argument to slot. so i'm using signal mapping . I'm passing the QlinEedit variable as a argument to the slot using setmapping . but my slot function is not calling.

```
QSignalMapper* maper = new QSignalMapper (this) ;
connect(ui->step2,SIGNAL(returnPressed()),maper,SLOT(map()));
maper->setMapping(ui->step2,ui->step2);
connect (maper, SIGNAL(mapped(QLineEdit*)), this, SLOT(on_steps_returnPressed(QLineEdit*))) ;
```

Comment: You should use the new signals/slots version and a lambda instead of a signal mapper

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but I'd recommend always using the new type safe signal/slot connection syntax based on member function pointers rather than the old string based `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` macros that can only report errors at run-time (and are slower).

Comment: The signal is mapped(QWidget*), not mapped(QLineEdit*)

Comment: Also not working with  mapped(QWidget*)

Answer (score 0):

The `QSignalMapper` class is deprecated and you should use the new signal/slots syntax with a lambda function:

```
connect(ui->step2, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, [=]() { this->on_steps_returnPressed(ui->step2); });
```

You can also pass only the text inside you `QLineEdit` instead of a pointer on it:

```
connect(ui->step2, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, [=]() { this->on_steps_returnPressed(ui->step2->text()); });
```

If you have to use a `QSignalMapper` anyway, you have to use the signal `QSignalMapper::mapped(QWidget*)`. Since a slot has to have the same signature than the connected signal, `on_steps_returnPressed` becomes `on_steps_returnPressed(QWidget*)` (cast the parameter to a `QLineEdit`):

```
QSignalMapper* maper = new QSignalMapper (this) ;
connect(step2, SIGNAL(returnPressed()), maper, SLOT(map()));
maper->setMapping(step2, step2);
connect(maper, SIGNAL(mapped(QWidget*)), this, SLOT(on_steps_returnPressed(QWidget*)));
```

Your slot should be something like that:

```
void on_steps_returnPressed(QWidget* widget)
{
    QLineEdit* edit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(widget);
    if (!edit)
        return;
    label->setText(edit->text());
}
```

A complete example to compare the two solutions:

```
class Widget: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Widget(QWidget* parent=nullptr): QWidget(parent),
        lineEdit1(new QLineEdit(this)),
        lineEdit2(new QLineEdit(this)),
        label(new QLabel(this))
    {
        QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        layout->addWidget(lineEdit1);
        layout->addWidget(lineEdit2);
        layout->addWidget(label);

        connect(lineEdit1, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, [=]() { this->on_steps_returnPressed(lineEdit1); });

        QSignalMapper* maper = new QSignalMapper (this) ;
        connect(lineEdit2, SIGNAL(returnPressed()), maper, SLOT(map()));
        maper->setMapping(lineEdit2, lineEdit2);
        connect(maper, SIGNAL(mapped(QWidget*)), this, SLOT(on_steps_returnPressed(QWidget*)));
    }

public slots:
    void on_steps_returnPressed(QLineEdit* edit)
    {
        label->setText(edit->text());
    }
    void on_steps_returnPressed(QWidget* widget)
    {
        QLineEdit* edit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(widget);
        if (!edit)
            return;
        label->setText(edit->text());
    }
private:
    QLineEdit* lineEdit1;
    QLineEdit* lineEdit2;
    QLabel* label;
};
```